# Java how to use methods from another module in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have added two projects as modules in empty intellij project.
Then I added in pom of module B following dependency to first project(module A):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>Group</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This allows me to import classes from module A into module B.
But I can't see any method from that module (it looks like classes are empty or they have only private fields/methods).

What am I missing? What should I do to see all public methods/fields from A module?

Thanks
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding one of them as a dependency, you can avoid to join them as modules. For local purposes, you can build(`mvn clean package`) one of them and add that as a dependency to another one. You can check relevant `.class` file to see the access levels of the class members. 
For multi-module projects, please, see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to use that second module in multi-module?
I have two modules like in your link, but how should i attach one to another to use them?

Comment: @Kamil1014, that might be helpful for you: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module.

Comment: @Kamil1014, could you please, then set my answer as `accepted` ;).